# Find one moebius transformation which returns a segment for a given arc of a circle

Tags: geometry, mobius-transformation

I'm doing some 2d geometry and I think the moebius transformation (as documented here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation) can give me the answer I'm looking for, but I'm stuck.

[image]

I start from an arc of a circle, defined by its center, its radius, and two angles (at which the arc start and stop).

- Any transformation which can give map each point of the arc to a point of the segment would be good enough (bijection seems trivial here).
- A better solution would preserve the fact that M is at the middle of AB (so M' at the middle of A'B')
- The perfect solution (but I don't know if it exists) would be that the curvilinear abscissa of M on the arc is equal the the one of M' on the segment for all M in [A, B].

The position or the orientation of the resulting segment is not important.

What would be the best way to find the a, b, c, d parameters of the moebius transformation ?

Comment: A mobius transformation is determined by its value on $3$ points, so just pick the unique one sending $A$ to $A'$, $M$ to $M'$, $B$ to $B'$. This will let you send $M$ to a midpoint, and even pick exactly the location and orientation of the segment (though you indicated that's less important).

Comment: @TokenToucan Thanks, I'll try that (if successfull, I'll post)

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{bmatrix}
B - M & AM-AB\\
A + B - 2 M & BM + AM - 2AB
\end{bmatrix}$$
This sends any three points distinct points $A,B,M$ to $0,1,1/2$, respectively. Since mobius transformations take arcs/lines to arcs/lines and your three points are on a common arc, this will take that arc to the line from 0 to 1.

I computed this in Sage - you can replicate it by using the "point_transformation_matrix" method for projective space. There is probably an easier way, as to use that method you will have to projectivize your coordinates and then dehomogenize at the end.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.- (1) The function $f$ (blue color in the attached figure) defined by $f(P)=Q$ is a bijection of the arc $AB$ on the line segment $CD$ contained in the tangent to the circle at the midpoint $M$.

(2) Apply this segment $CD$ on segment $A'B'$ using a function $g$ similar to $f$.

(3) One function that answers the problem is $g\circ f$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Piquito and @TokenToucan. Your answers are perfect, I couldn't get better, only more complex. My solution also miss the linearity of the coordinates after and before the projection (but it does use the möbius transformation :D)

I wanted to use the moebius formula, so while I waited for clues, I tried to find $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ of

$$ f(z) = \frac{a z + b}{c z + d} $$

Such as the three point of the arc $P_i$, $P_j$ and $P_k$ (respectively at start, middle and end of the arc) maps to $Q_i$, $Q_j$ and $Q_k$ (respectively at start, middle and end of a segment). And the result is hellish ! But seems to be correct.

$d$ can be fixed freely,

$$ d = 1 $$

$$ c = \frac{d \left(P_{i} Q_{j} - P_{i} Q_{k} - P_{j} Q_{i} + P_{j} Q_{k} + P_{k} Q_{i} - P_{k} Q_{j}\right)}{P_{i} P_{j} Q_{i} - P_{i} P_{j} Q_{j} - P_{i} P_{k} Q_{i} + P_{i} P_{k} Q_{k} + P_{j} P_{k} Q_{j} - P_{j} P_{k} Q_{k}} $$

$$ b = \frac{- P_{i} P_{j} Q_{i} c + P_{i} P_{j} Q_{j} c + P_{i} Q_{j} d - P_{j} Q_{i} d}{P_{i} - P_{j}} $$

$$ a = \frac{P_{i} Q_{i} c + Q_{i} d - b}{P_{i}} $$

---

Which gives, for the example of @Piquito:

$$ P_i = (1, 0), P_j = \left( \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \right ), P_k = (0, 1) $$

$$ Q_i = (\sqrt 2, 0), Q_j = \left( \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} \right ), Q_k = (0, \sqrt 2) $$

The following parameters for the möbius transformation :

$$ a = 2 + \sqrt 2$$
$$ b = -1 - i $$
$$ c = \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} i $$
$$ d = 1 $$

[image: blue before, orange after transformation]

What is funny is that the result is clearly different from a geometric projection... but the curvilinear abscissa transformation is it not linear neither.